# Windows Phone 7 - Toggle switch in list box

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, viewmodel

In a group of toggle switches I couldn't control the any toggle switch individually, rather if I try to change one then all the values change simultaneously.

My Xaml:-

```
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="yourChoiceListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476" ItemsSource="{Binding yourChoiceList, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">

                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="476" Height="60">
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Black" Width="250" Text="{Binding title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="35" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Black" Width="150" Text="{Binding valueDesc}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding valueVisible}" />
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggle" Foreground="Black" Content="{Binding toggleContent}" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.isCheck,ElementName=yourChoiceListBox,Mode=TwoWay}"  Height="110" Width="198" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="40,-15,0,0" Visibility="{Binding tongleVisible}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Border>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
```

My ViewModel CS:-

```
  public static string _toggleContent;
        public string toggleContent
        {
            get { return _toggleContent; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.toggleContent, value); }
        }

        public static bool _isCheck;
        public bool isCheck
        {
            get { return _isCheck; }
            set
            {
                this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.isCheck, value);
                if (isCheck)
                    toggleContent = "Yes";
                else
                    toggleContent = "No";
            }
        }
```

Here i want to change the toggle switch content in to "Yes" or "No". If i choose 'On' the content should be "Yes". But here if i select one toggle switch all the toggle switch is changed. Please let me any idea to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your IsChecked property Binding is wrong it shouldn't bind on the listbox but on the data item

Comment: Hi @csharpwinphonexaml.. Please give any example?

Comment: Check the answer I wrote for you

Answer (score 0):

This is your ToggleSwitch:

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggle" Foreground="Black" Content="{Binding toggleContent}" 
    IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.isCheck,ElementName=yourChoiceListBox,Mode=TwoWay}"  
    Height="110" Width="198" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="40,-15,0,0" 
    Visibility="{Binding tongleVisible}" />
```

the problem is here:

```
IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.isCheck,ElementName=yourChoiceListBox,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

You are binding the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleSwitch` to the `isCheck` property of your **list**.

You should bind the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleSwitch` to the `isCheck` property of your **list item** like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding isCheck, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: But here i can not change the Content. The default content is On/Off. But i want to change Yes/No. If i use toggle switch normally i can change the Content. If i use the toggle in list box i can not change the content. Please let me any idea.

Comment: make your object an `INotifyPropertyChanged` and it will be automatically done by itself

Comment: Hi @csharpwinphonexaml.. Thanks for reply. For  `INotifyPropertyChanged` I am using `reactive Object`. Actually my requirement is i want write event for the toggle switch which is inside the ListBox. Is there any examples for this?

Comment: May I take a closer look to the whole thing?

Comment: write me on stackoverflow@robyapps.com

Comment: Hi.. I can not send mail to this mail id.

Comment: Sorry my email box was full